# What is the difference between `&` v.s. `,` when using dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've read some dplyr [vignettes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) and dplyr::filter [example](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html), I'm curious does there has any difference between **`&`** and **`,`** when subset rows using column values? Because the result is identical, I just afraid could make some semantic errors. Below is paste directly from the example:

- Filtering by multiple criteria within a single logical expression:

`filter(starwars, hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black")`

`filter(starwars, hair_color == "none", eye_color == "black")`

```
# A tibble: 9 × 14
  name       height  mass hair_color skin_color    eye_color birth_year sex   gender
  <chr>       <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1 Nien Nunb     160    68 none       grey          black             NA male  mascu…
2 Gasgano       122    NA none       white, blue   black             NA male  mascu…
3 Kit Fisto     196    87 none       green         black             NA male  mascu…
... with more entries and variables ...
```

---

And could I put them together? Using `&` `,` within a single expression? Like below:

`filter(starwars, hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black", gender == "masculine")`

`filter(starwars, hair_color == "none", eye_color == "black" & gender == "masculine")`

```
# A tibble: 7 × 14
  name       height  mass hair_color skin_color  eye_color birth_year sex   gender  
  <chr>       <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
1 Nien Nunb     160    68 none       grey        black             NA male  masculi…
2 Gasgano       122    NA none       white, blue black             NA male  masculi…
3 Kit Fisto     196    87 none       green       black             NA male  masculi…
... with more entries and variables ...
```

Because the result is also identical, thanks in advance!

Comment: They are identical.  From the documentation: `If multiple expressions are included, they are combined with the & operator. `.

Comment: `?filter` says "If multiple expressions are included, they are combined with the ‘&’ operator."; the two forms are identical.

Comment: I think that the expressions separated by comma are internally connected via a boolean and `&` so comma and `&` are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (`?dplyr::filter`):

> If multiple expressions are included, they are combined with the `&` operator.

Therefore, using `,` and `&` is identical.

---

<sup>This answer comes from @RitchieSacramento's comment and was posted a month after. I don't want to steal credit, I just want this question to stop appearing as "unanswered" while it is actually answered.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @bretauv, this is my first question at SO, I was unable to found the way to mark  the comment as an answer. Thank you all to comment and answer!

Comment: @WillHong that's simply because you can't mark comments as answers so it's normal. Usually, you can ask the person who wrote the comment to put it as an answer so that you can validate it.